# @font-face not showing when css is placed in folder

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

@font-face does not work when i place the CSS file in any folder except the project root folder (/project).

I could change the location of the `font file` for all I care and the @font-face `url` is accurate but if i shift the CSS file, the page breaks.

All the docs, similar solutions and common sense state that the relative path of the css to the `font file` is the problem but I've tried changing the relative path and even used absolute paths and still, zilch. This is my folder structure:

[image: This is my folder structure]

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia assumenda necessitatibus inventore sed voluptatem commodi incidunt exercitationem, laborum iusto quidem cupiditate eum perspiciatis debitis. Eum qui voluptatem quasi laboriosam dolore?
</body>
</html>
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "rubikbubbles";
  src: url("../fonts/RubikBubbles/RubikBubbles-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
body {
  font-family: "rubikrubbles";
  font-size: 50px;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=custom.css.map */
```

Comment: URLS are loaded based on what path your server puts things on, not your file system. So open dev tools, look at the "network" tab, and just look at which URLs your page is trying to load assets from. Should be easy to spot, they'll be 404s

Comment: Hmm only assets listed are the html (303) and css (303) and "WS" (101) files. Did I miss something?

Comment: Open the CSS url and see if it even _has_ anything `@font-face` in it, because it sounds like it doesn't. If it did, you're also see a download attempt for a font asset. That said: make sure to show "all" requests, because sometimes it's not set to that.

Comment: The CSS url seems to contain just the contents I put up in the original question. I've put up screenshots of the network tab segments on imgur if you could have a look. Thanks!!!  1. [CSS URL Network-Tab "Headers"](https://imgur.com/STWHUku)  2.[CSS URL Network-Tab "Headers"](https://imgur.com/IcNVhI7) 3. [CSS URL Network-Tab "Initiator"](https://imgur.com/6dgQ0so).

Comment: I believe the current relative file path is going to dist/fonts. Try "../../fonts/RubikBubbles/RubikBubbles-Regular.ttf"

Comment: Changing the path to "../../fonts/RubikBubbles/RubikBubbles-Regular.ttf" changes nothing.

Comment: If there is no font entire in your network tab, then your CSS is _not_ asking the browser to load a font, so if you can show what the browser actually loads when you open that CSS file from the network tab (right click, open in new tab, and then copy-paste that into your post.

Comment: ```css
@font-face { font-family: "rubikbubbles"; 
src: url("../../fonts/RubikBubbles/RubikBubbles-Regular.ttf") format("truetype"); } body { 
font-family: "rubikrubbles"; 
font-size: 50px; }/*
# sourceMappingURL=custom.css.map */
```


Copy-pasted this by opening the custom.css file (in another tab) from the network tab. Do let me know if I'm doing this wrong still. Appreciate your help!!!